# How native types passed by value to delegate are treated?

Tags: c++-cli

What happens with native classes passed by value to delegate call?

Here is a code that confuse me. My expectations about Native's ctor/dtor calls are commented in the code.

Output:
Native ctor 3207236
Native copy ctor 3207240
m1
Native dtor 3207240
m2
Native dtor 3207240
m3
Native dtor 3207240
Native dtor 3207236

Real result is very strange for me:
    **Every delegate handler calls Native's dtor but Native's copy ctor is call only once (during a delegate call).**

It means that object that is passed to the delegate by value is created once (via copy ctor) but its dtor is called there are **3(!)** times!
I don't understand why.

Could someone explain me why my expectations failed?

```
class Native
{
public:
  Native()
  {
     Console::WriteLine("Native ctor {0}", __int64(this));
  }

  ~Native()
  {
     Console::WriteLine("Native dtor {0}", __int64(this));
  }

  Native(const Native& nat)
  {
     Console::WriteLine("Native copy ctor {0}", __int64(this));
  }
};

ref class Managed
{
public:
  delegate void Dele(Native);
  Dele^ m_delegate;

  Managed()
  {
     m_delegate = static_cast<Dele^>(Delegate::Combine(gcnew Dele(this, &Managed::m1), gcnew Dele(this, &Managed::m2), gcnew Dele(this, &Managed::m3)));
  }

  void m1(Native nat) // Expected: Native's copy ctor is called before Delegate calls the method 
                      // Reality: NO
  {
     Console::WriteLine("m1");
  } // Expected: Native's dtor is called; Reality: YES

  void m2(Native nat) // Expected: Native's copy ctor is called before Delegate calls the method
                    // Reality: NO
  {
     Console::WriteLine("m2");
  } // Expected: Native's dtor is called; Reality: YES

  void m3(Native nat) // Expected: Native's copy ctor is called before Delegate calls the method
                     // Reality: NO
  {
     Console::WriteLine("m3");
  } // Expected: Native's dtor is called; Reality: YES
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
   Native n; // Expected: Native's ctor is called; Reality: YES.
   Managed^ man = gcnew Managed();
   man->m_delegate(n); // Native's copy ctor is called; Reality: YES
   return 0;
} // Expected: Native's dtor is called; Reality: YES
```

Comment: Yes, you can call this a bug.  No point in reporting it, this is very hard to fix.  The CLR assumes value-type behavior when it generates the stubs for the delegates, it has no mechanism for dealing with value type values that become invalid.  You need to work around this by passing the argument by reference.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I have done it as you advised me. Could you tell me where I can read more about proxy/stub generation. I guess it is similar COM proxy/stub. I remember that there was a way to write and register custom marshaling.

Comment: I don't know of any place where this is documented, other than the CLR source code.  Available in the SSCLI20 distribution, it is a tough read.  Doesn't have anything to do with COM proxies btw.

Comment: @Hans you may be interested in [this breaking news](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/02/03/coreclr-is-now-open-source.aspx) ;)